# Determining content scaling in a PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF that contains an image of a scanned document. The page content is as follows:

**First Content Stream**

```
0.36 0 0 0.36 0 0 cm
q
  2200 0 0 1700 0 0 cm
  /Im1 Do
Q
```

It appears that the page is scaled to 36% of its original size. Additionally, this is done without a save/restore so it effects subsequent streams in the page.

I need to add text to the page with PDFBox with a new content stream. In order to fix the scaling, I've calculated the inverse of the scaling and added it before my text:

**Second Content Stream**

```
q
  2.77778 0 0 2.77778 0 0 cm
  BT
    0 Tr
    /F1 37.75083 Tf
    67 531 Td
    /DeviceRGB cs
    1 0 0 sc
    1 0 0 1 67 531 Tm
    (\000U\000R\000J\000H\000U\000V\000R\000Q) Tj
  ET
Q
```

This works fine but I need to calculate the scaling programatically based off the page's current state instead of a hard coded value. I'm trying to use PDFBox to find the current scaling but it's always 1.0:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void debug() {
        var source = new ClassPathResource("pdf/scaling/test.pdf").getFile();
        @Cleanup var pdf = PDDocument.load(source);
        var page = pdf.getPage(0);
        assertEquals(0.36, page.getMatrix().getScaleX());
        assertEquals(0.36, page.getMatrix().getScaleY());
    }
```

```
AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :0.36
Actual   :1.0
```

I'm assuming that the page needs to be rendered to determine the actual scaling. Using PDFStreamEngine to process the page, I still see the scaling as 1:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void scalingDetection() {
        var source = new ClassPathResource("pdf/scaling/test.pdf").getFile();
        @Cleanup var pdf = PDDocument.load(source);
        DebugStreamEngine engine = new DebugStreamEngine();
        engine.processPage(pdf.getPage(0));
        assertEquals(0.36f, engine.getScalingX());
        assertEquals(0.36f, engine.getScalingY());
    }
    

    protected class DebugStreamEngine extends PDFStreamEngine {
        public DebugStreamEngine() {
            addOperator(new Concatenate());
            addOperator(new DrawObjectOperator());
            addOperator(new BeginInlineImageOperator());
            addOperator(new SetGraphicsStateParameters());
            addOperator(new Save());
            addOperator(new Restore());
            addOperator(new SetMatrix());
        }

        @Override
        protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            log.info("Processing operator: {}", operator.getName());
        }
        
        protected float getScalingX() {
            return getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix().getScaleX();
        }
        
        protected float getScalingY() {
            return getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix().getScaleY();
        }
    }
```

```
AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :0.36
Actual   :1.0
```

I think this may be caused by a reset of the graphics stack in PDFStreamEngine.processStream. I've worked around it by maintaining my own graphics stack but I'm wondering if I've missed a better solution or if this could be a bug in PDBox?

Comment: *"I need to add text to the page with PDFBox with a new content stream. In order to fix the scaling, I've calculated the inverse of the scaling and added it before my text"* - have you considered wrapping the existing content stream in a `q .. Q` envelope so that you can start your appended content stream with the identity matrix? That's what the `boolean resetContext` parameter of some `PDPageContentStream` is there for...

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from modifying any existing content streams but I could probably make that work. I'm working with some constraints that generally frown on making content modifications vs adding content.

Comment: *"I'm trying to stay away from modifying any existing content streams"* - The option I referred to adds the `q .. Q` envelope in extra content streams, not in the existing one.

Comment: As an aside, not only the scaling can be an issue to you, other PDFs might have changed colors, rendering modes, blend modes, transparency masks, clip paths, ... and not all of these can be reset without a `Q` restore of an original state saved with `q`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That works perfectly. Thanks for the clarification. I'll update the issue with a detailed answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on MKL and KJ's comments, I've removed the need to determine/revert the scaling. This is done by adding the flag to reset the context when creating a content stream.  This also helps prevent other potential problems that I had not accounted for.

Adding this flag prepends a content stream with a single `q` operator. Then the new (appended) stream is started with a `Q` operator. The compiled result being:

**Prepended Stream**

```
q
```

**Original Stream**

```
0.36 0 0 0.36 0 0 cm
q
  2200 0 0 1700 0 0 cm
  /Im1 Do
Q
```

**Appended Stream**

```
Q
q
BT
  0 Tr
  /F1 37.75083 Tf
  67 531 Td
  /DeviceRGB cs
  1 0 0 sc
  1 0 0 1 67 531 Tm
  (\000U\000R\000J\000H\000U\000V\000R\000Q) Tj
ET
Q
```

Comment: Be aware that, in the mists of time, before ISO standardisation, the spec did not require that there was a Q for every q - trailing Qs could be omitted. Such files are fairly rare, but exist - and your method could fail on them, depending on the implementation of the resetContext you mention. Have you checked?

Comment: That's certainly an interesting problem that I didn't think about. I'm not sure if there's any accounting for it in the PDFBox code but it seems like maybe that's just something I'd push back onto our clients as a problem for them to resolve.